# How do I change the date formatting of a column and determine the number of years in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to figure out how to mass change the date formatting of my data (as there are millions of data on the dataset) using Jupyter Notebook as the two datasets given to me has a different date format. Tried to google for codes on how to change the date format but hasn't been successful. For example, I would like to change the date formatting for "Discharged" and the initial dataset after merging to a dataframe and the desired output would look something like this

**Dataset (Merged using Dataframe)**

| ID | Age | Date Seen | Date Discharged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 21 | 2019-10-22 | 02-02-2022 08:00:00PM |
| 002 | 18 | 2013-05-24 | 15-05-2019 06:30:00PM |

**Desired Output**

| ID | Age | Date Seen | Date Discharged | Calculated Years (Round Up) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 21 | 2019-10-22 | 2022-02-02 | 3 |
| 002 | 18 | 2013-05-24 | 2019-05-15 | 6 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dt.normalize`:

```
# Convert to datetime64 if it's not already the case
df['Date Seen'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Seen'])
df['Date Discharged'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Discharged'])

# Keep date part and compute years
df['Date Discharged'] = df['Date Discharged'].dt.normalize()
df['Years'] = df['Date Discharged'].dt.year - df['Date Seen'].dt.year
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     ID  Age  Date Seen Date Discharged  Years
0   001   21 2019-10-22      2022-02-02      3
1   002   18 2013-05-24      2019-05-15      6
```

Comment: @DT. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I tried changing 'Date Discharged' to datetime64 but an error came up " 'Dataframe' object has no attribute 'to_datetime' ". I suspect it may be the AM that is causing the error as it is now being read as an object rather than datetime64 for the other columns with the 'Date Seen' formatting. The current formatting for 'Date Discharged' is eg. 5/15/2009 8:40:00 AM. How do i rectify this error?

Comment: Why `pd` is a dataframe? Do you use anywhere in your code `pd = pd.DataFrame` or something else? What is the output of `type(pd)`? Do you import pandas with `import pandas as pd`?

Comment: And no AM should not be the problem.

Comment: Yup in my code there was pd but the dataset used to convert to datetime are merged pd. I did import pandas with pd. I'm suspecting that there may be accidental entry of other letters or words in the dataset like "Unknown". In that case, is there any quick way to check those or am i left with checking them 1 by 1 using excel?

Comment: Hi just an update, just realised for one of the dataset, the date was not standardized. Some showed 23/10/2012 and some showed 10/23/2012 which might have caused the issue. In that case, how do I standardize the date for the particular dataset first?

Comment: Try something like: `df['Date Seen'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Seen'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').combine_first(pd.to_datetime(df['Date Seen'], dayfirst=False, errors='coerce')`

Comment: Sorry for the really late update as i was attempting to clean the data in the excel spreadsheet. This really helped and solved my issue! Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it!